# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Could not add one or more tag libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty, osgi

I have an OSGi application that was developed by some of my fellow students and I try to get it running in Eclipse Juno 4.2 with Java 1.6 under OS X 10.8. One of the bundles of this application is responsible for providing a web interface using JSP and Jetty. When I try to run the project in Eclipse, the Equinox console gives me the following exception when I try to access the web interface:

```
2012-08-21 16:15:30.574:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/ner/ner
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/ner.jsp(5,68) PWC6226: Could not add one or more tag libraries.

at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:258)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:229)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:145)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:212)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:98)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at de.uni_sb.coli.nep.webui.NerServlet.doGet(NerServlet.java:150)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The web interface-related folder structure is as follows:

```
WebContent
|----> WEB-INF
       |----> ner.jsp     # This is the template
              lib
              |----> commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
                     commons-io-2.0.1.jar
              tld
              |----> c-1_0-rt.tld
                     c-1_0.tld
                     c.tld
                     fmt-1_0-rt.tld
                     fmt-1_0.tld
                     fmt.tld
                     fn.tld
                     permittedTaglibs.tld
                     scriptfree.tld
                     sql-1_0-rt.tld
                     sql-1_0.tld
                     sql.tld
                     x-1_0-rt.tld
                     x-1_0.tld
                     x.tld
```

The web interface should be accessible at `http://localhost:8080/ner/ner` but Jetty only gives me a HTTP 500 with the same exception as stated above. In the terminal, everything goes fine but not in Eclipse. It seems that Eclipse is expecting a different folder structure or something.

Do you have any idea what could cause this problem? If you need to see the content of some files, let me know and I will add them to this post. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found this error to be a royal PITA - unfortunately it can come from more than one source.  The error message seems to be a bit of a catch all for several different conditions.

First off, you need to ensure that the libraries you use in your war file are all "properly aligned".  I found this question to be best answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094329/tomcat-7-and-jstl).

That still might not fix things though - it didn't here!  So if you have your own tag library and use a reserved word, that also appears to cause the error.

For example:

```
    <jsp:directive.attribute
            name="minimize"
            type="java.lang.Boolean"
            required="true"
            description="Compress something"/>
```

in this case "minimize" causes a conflict and can be reported via this error message.