# JSTL, Tomcat6 -> Tomcat7 upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jstl, tomcat7

I am in the process of upgrading tomcat6 to tomcat7. Currently the application deploys and works fine on tomcat6.

This is the config:

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

in .jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

I have the jstl-1.2.jar, jstl-api-1.2.jar, jstl-1.2jar in my Tomcat/lib directory (same as Tomcat6).

I end up getting 
various exceptions related to this, such as:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/tags/form/show.tagx (line: 25, column: 89) "${object.class.simpleName}.field.${property}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${object.class.simpleName}.field.${property}]
```

in my pom.xml I am pulling in

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Should Tomcat7 not support 2.5? I have tried using 3.0 but to no avail. Any insight appreciated. I have tried some of the solutions provided here:

[How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/jstl-1-2-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved)

[Tomcat 7 and JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094329/tomcat-7-and-jstl)

but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The identifier `[class]` is not a valid Java identifier as required by EL specification. This check can be disabled by setting the system property `org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK` to true.

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

Or you can use the following expression equivalent one instead:

```
${object.['class'].simpleName}.field.${property}
```