# Tomcat is not processing jstl ${}

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I am running tomcat7 on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance. For some reason that I cannot figure out, the jstl `${}` syntax is not getting processed. What is weird, at least in my mind, is that the `<c:forEach />` tags are getting processed correctly.

So for example, I have this in my jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${flavors}" var = "f">
    ${f.value}
</c:forEach>
```

And this is what is getting printed on my page : `${f.value}`.

So, the `<c:forEach />` tag does not get printed out but the `${}` synatax does.

I have verifed that there are 4 elements in the flavors list by viewing them with `<%= request.getAttribute("flavors")%>`.

Any idea what is going on and how to fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added relevant portion of my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>${jstl.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: have you considered upgrading to Tomcat 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pl add following attribute to top of jsp.  `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

Comment: Did you leave part of your answer out?

Answer (score 0):

You need the JSTL libraries on your tomcat lib. Refer to the links below:
[Running JSTL on Tomcat 7](http://www.murraywilliams.com/2011/11/running-jstl-1-2-on-tomcat-7-using-maven/) and download from: [Tomcat JSTL libraries dowload](https://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/) Also here: [Tomcat 7 and JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094329/tomcat-7-and-jstl)

Comment: The only dependency from the blog I was missing was the glassfish one, and I added it, rebuilt the war, deployed it, and nothing changed.

Comment: I am not sure if that last link you shared applies because tomcat is having no problems with `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`

Comment: Did you follow the entire answers on the 3rd link. Check the solution with score 38. You have the 2 exclusions but not the 3rd `<exclusion>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        </exclusion>` I think you should also show your `web.xml` if you still having problems.