# Spring boot - Adding JSTL dependency causes a problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jstl

I am new to Spring boot. I want to use `jstl` tag for JSP page. For that I have added the following dependency

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Whenever I add the `jstl` dependency the project wont start but will start when removing it.

> Deploying on Apache Tomcat 8.0.27.0
>       profile mode: false
>       debug mode: true
>       force redeploy: true Undeploying ... undeploy?path=/demo OK - Undeployed application at context path /demo In-place deployment at

Following error appears while running app.

> C:\Users\Nishan
>   Dhungana\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SpringBootTest\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FNISHAN%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext3041249382478705791.xml&path=/demo
>   FAIL - Deployed application at context path /demo but context failed
>   to start

Comment: whats the exact exception ?

Comment: just want to run the application. Project doesn't start (Deployement failed) after adding jstl dependency but work fine while removing it

Comment: can you post application.properties content

Comment: Shouldn't you add <version> to all your Maven dependencies?  I do.

Comment: @benjaminc - Just `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` this on application.properties

Comment: @duffymo - does version matters. I am using NetBeans and it suggest me to remove version tag. Even adding version tag doesn't work

Comment: Version matters, of course, but that might not be the root of your problem.  Consider it an observation.  Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094329/tomcat-7-and-jstl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this dependency too in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>jstl</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this might help you!